# two recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

How to solve the below relation

This will not be a balanced tree.
and for k levels i have something like

How can i find the T(n) for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You are building a tree at every level of which you pay at most $cn$. As you mention, the number of levels for which this goes on is at most $\log_{100/99} n$. We pay at most $cn\log_{100/99} n$. The solution of the recurrence is $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.